# js differentiate regexp capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Is there a way in javascript/node.js to differentiate capture groups created by a regexp ? For example, this regexp: `/([A-Z]+\[[^\]]+])|(\d+)/g` on the text: `9 and 4687 matches but not NUMBER[9] or NUMBER[9568] However, [401] should match...` will create two capture groups:

- group 1: NUMBER[9] & NUMBER[9568]
- group 2: 9, 4687 & 401

What I want is to add the tag `NUMBER[]` around numbers on my text. Is there a way to do something like `text.replace(regexp, 'NUMBER[$&]', SECOND_GROUP)` ?

EDIT: The output would be `NUMBER[9] and NUMBER[4687] matches but not NUMBER[9] or NUMBER[9568] However, [NUMBER[401]] should match...`

Comment: It is easy with `String#replace`, but do you really want to get `[NUMBER[401]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a callback method as a replacement argument in [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to check if a specific group matched, and perform appropriate replacement logic inside the anonymous method:

```js
var regex = /([A-Z]+\[[^\]]+])|(\d+)/g;
var str = `9 and 4687 matches but not NUMBER[9] or NUMBER[9568] However, [401] should match...`;
var res = str.replace(regex, function($0,$1,$2) {
  return $2 ? "NUMBER[" + $2 + "]" : $0; // If Group 2 matched, use special value, else paste back the match
});
console.log(res);
```

The `$0` stands for the whole match, `$1` represents Group 1 contents, and `$2` refer to the Group 2 contents.

You may add more logic to also account for specific Group 1 match treatment.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that String#replace could take a function as argument!